# display Bootstrap 4 cards with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, pagination

I Want to Display The Content of my database as Bootstrap Cards and I Want to add a pagination, so I can display 10 cards at once
this is an example of what I want;
(using 'La ravel')

[here](https://www.phpflow.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/product-grid-view.png)

Comment: can you add a bit of code of what you have so far? so we can work from what you have?

Comment: So what is your problem or did you try anything???? Let us see

Answer (score 1):

That should be fairly simple to do. 
In your ProductController paginate your products

```
public function index()
{
    return view('products.index')->withProducts(Product::paginate(10));
}
```

In your view

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/'.$product->image)}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ $product->title }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ $product->description }}</p>
            <a href="{{ route('products.show', $product->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">More details</a>
        </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

And somewhere in your page render pagination links

```
@if($products->count())
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ $products->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your Help